# Field as a subset of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be any non-zero vector space over $k$, then $k=span(\{1_k\})$ forms a one-dimensional vector space, but how can I show $k\subset V$? Or is there a counter example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $V$ is non-trivial. Fix a vector $v\neq 0$ in $V$. Simply define the injection

$$k\to V: \lambda \to \lambda v$$

This does not work if $V$ is the nullspace.

If you meant a formal inclusion, this is in general false.

Comment: I see. But we can say that $k$ is a vector space that is isomorphic to $\phi_v(k)$, which is a one-dimensional subspace of $V$?

Comment: Yes, that's what my answer shows. The function I wrote down is an isomorphism onto its image.

Comment: In general, $k$ isn’t a subset of $V$ except, e.g., $V=k$.  Remember that the span of a set of vectors contains vectors as elements, not elements of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prove it since it is not true. For instance, $k\not\subset k^2$.

Comment: Surely $k^2$ has a standard basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ where $e_1=1_k$?

Comment: Not true, since $e_1=(1,0)\neq1_k$. Actually, $1_k\notin k^2$.

Comment: Careful. The elements of $k^2$ are tupels. The elements of $k$ are not. So, they can't be subsets of each other.

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ is a vector space over a field $k$, then $k$ (itself a vector space of dimension $1$ over $k$, trivially) is isomorphic (as a vector space) with any subspace $\langle v_o\rangle = \{tv_0: t \in k\}$, with $v_0 \neq 0$ in $V$. This is easy to check.